# Cordova Reverse Geocoding returning an error

Tags: javascript, cordova, google-maps, plugins

I am really battling with the plugin cordova-plugin-googlemaps reverse geocoding lookup.

All I want to do is provide latitude and longitude and return the street address, something I thought would be very simple.

The documentation is non-existant, and if I use the provided example, all I get is an error saying 'Not Found'.

```
var request = {
  'position': GOOGLE
};
plugin.google.maps.Geocoder.geocode(request, function(results) {
  if (results.length) {
    var result = results[0];
    var position = result.position; 
    var address = [
      result.subThoroughfare || "",
      result.thoroughfare || "",
      result.locality || "",
      result.adminArea || "",
      result.postalCode || "",
      result.country || ""].join(", ");

    alert(address);
  } else {
    alert("Not found");
  }
});
```

I don't know what 'GOOGLE' is referring to under the var request.  I tried putting the co-ordinates there, but I just get an error back.  Again, there is no documentation anywhere for this!

Please any help would be fantastic

Comment: According to your question about what GOOGLE refers to, it's a variable/constant declared earlier in se part of the documentation as `const GOOGLE = {lat: ..., lng: ...}` it's basically the coordinates of Google's physical address. Just pass your own longitude and latitude values.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the link to the docs for geocoding: https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/wiki/Geocoder

I think, you have mixed some examples from the docs. ;-))

Just give the plugin an search address like:

```
var request = "New York, Fifth Avenue";
```

Update:

And you have to whitelisten the google url.

Answer (score 0):

Reverse geocoding document.
https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps-doc/blob/master/v2.3.0/class/Geocoder/reverse_geocoding/README.md

```js
plugin.google.maps.Geocoder.geocode({
  "position": {
     lat: ...
     lng: ...
  }
}, function(results) {

  if (results.length === 0) {
    // Not found
    return;
  }

  var address = [
    results[0].subThoroughfare || "",
    results[0].thoroughfare || "",
    results[0].locality || "",
    results[0].adminArea || "",
    results[0].postalCode || "",
    results[0].country || ""].join(", ");

  marker.setTitle(address)
        .showInfoWindow();
});
```